# Display currency format using kable with Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to display a R data.frame in a HTML file created with R Markdown. I would like to display the numeric columns in this data.frame in a currency format like this : 800 124 €

Here is my code :

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---


```{r,echo=FALSE}
 test=data.frame(t1=c("Pres1","Pres2"),t2=c(800124,1236545),t3=c(565473,456841))
 library(knitr)
 kable(test,format.args=list(big.mark=" "))
```
````

I've tried to use the paste function to add the missing " €" string at the end of each cell but without success.

Is there a simple way to do that ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, you can represent the Euro with `&euro;`, `&#8364;`, or `&#x20AC;`, but you must include the semicolon.  The following works for me.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---


```{r,echo=FALSE}
append_euro <- function(x, ...){
  sprintf("%s &euro;",
          format(x, ...))
}

 test=data.frame(t1=c("Pres1","Pres2"),t2=c(800124,1236545),t3=c(565473,456841))
 test[c("t2", "t3")] <- 
   lapply(test[c("t2", "t3")],
          append_euro,
          big.mark = " ")
 library(knitr)

 kable(test)
```
````

Comment: Thank you it does exactly what I wanted